# SQL php Rollback does't work

Tags: php, sql

I have the following in php:

```
try {
    // INSERT FETCHED LIST INTO ARCHIVE
    $stmt1 = $sql->prepare('INSERT INTO hsarchive (LIST) VALUES (?)');
    $stmt1->bind_param("s",$total);
    $stmt1->execute();

    $stmt2 = $sql->prepare('TRUNCATE TABLE highscore');
    $stmt2->execute();

    $sql->rollback();
    $stmt1->close();
    $stmt2->close();

    } catch (Exception $e) {

    echo "error";
    $sql->rollback();

    }
```

Engine is InnoDB and the connection is started like:

```
$sql = getSQLAccess();
$sql->autocommit(false);
$sql->begin_transaction();
```

with getSQLAccess returning an object of the type connection with user, pw etc. in it.

No matter how I spin this, the table is truncated and the list is inserted into the archive. I tried switching around where I close the statements, and as you can see I'm currently not even committing, as I'm trying to figure out why the rollback doesnt work.

Anyone?

EDIT: So this would be the way to go, according to best answer:

```
try {

// INSERT FETCHED LIST INTO ARCHIVE
    $stmt = $sql->prepare('INSERT INTO hsarchive (LIST) VALUES (?)');
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$total);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

    $stmt = $sql->prepare('DELETE FROM highscore');
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

    $sql->commit();

    } catch (Exception $e) {
     $sql->rollback();
    }
```

Comment: Are there any foreign key constraints on `highscore` table?

Comment: Yes! They are foregin keys to a user table. I.e. the highscore contains ID of scorer and score, not their names, and then I use an INNER JOIN view to display names.

Comment: So, sorry, I mean: foreign key constraints that refer __to__ `highscore` table (i.e. from other tables to this)

Comment: No, there are not. Only views that join, but no constraints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**DDL in transactions**

Since we've figured out that *there are no FK constraints **to** table `highscore`* - then your issue is caused because since MySQL 5.0.3, [`TRUNCATE` table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html) syntax is equivalent to deletion of all rows *logically* but not *physically*

If there are no foreign key constraints to this table (your case) which restricts from doing this, MySQL will produce `TRUNCATE` operation via fast scheme: it will do `DROP` table + `CREATE` table. So while logically it's same to deletion of all rows, *it's not the same* in terms of how operation is maintained.

Why this is the difference? Because MySQL [doesn't support DDL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cannot-roll-back.html) in transactions. More precise, such operations can not be rolled back. For MySQL, DDL operations [will cause immediate implicit commit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/implicit-commit.html). That is why you see that your `TRUNCATE` statement: first, is committed even if you don't commit; second, rollback has no effect on it.

**Solution**

If you still need to rollback your operation, then, unfortunately, you'll need to use `DELETE` syntax instead of `TRUNCATE`. Unfortunately - because, obviously, `DELETE` is much slower than `TRUNCATE`, because rows will be processed one by one.

Comment: Thank you very much. I figured maybe it was something like this.
I figure I can just instead check the errorlevel of the previous transactions and then only call the TRUNCATE if all are 0?

Comment: You should not try to maintain atomicity and integrity on app level (it will alwais fail in terms of concurring connections). So use DBMS mechanism instead (like `DELETE` syntax for this issue).

Comment: First, this is another question, not an answer (so should be asked in another thread). Second - you'll have two operations then, so it breaks atomicity and can not be called transaction. It's hard to say for me if it "will work" (since I don't see clear picture) - but if logically this is the thing which you want - then do it, test it and see the result

Comment: I didn't know I could post code in comments - that's why.

I don't really know what atomicity is, and to me it seems that I'll have two operations now matter what? I guess I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: Your code isn't transaction since integrity, at least, isn't guaranteed. Imagine that your app process will fail (no matter why) at the line "catch". I.e. exception occured, but data won't be wiped out. That is why your idea has nothing to do with transactions - and can not maintain data integrity in common case

Comment: How would one make it properly then? Any operation can fail at the catch block (no matter why, as you say), and then what? If I don't reach the rollback then the data isn't committed either, I assume?

Comment: Proper solution: use commit/rollback + `DELETE` statement like I've suggested in the answer. Performance is the price for durability

Comment: And yes, it works, I just tried it. I realize it's not the right way to do it - for reasons you explain but I don't understand. I marked your answer as that's the reason it didn't work, which was what troubled me.